# Android: Cannot cancel custom dialog in a fragment in a viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my MainActivity, I have a fragment in a viewpager. In this fragment I build a custom dialog. The custom dialog can be cancel normally in other fragments which are called from MainActivity. However, in this fragment, it cannot be cancel. I don't know what happened with my dialog. Please help me to check the code below. Thanks in advance.

```
    dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.CustomDialogTheme);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_login_sns);

    LinearLayout cancelButton = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelButtonSNS);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("GETBOOKMARK", "call dialog cancel");
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `dismiss()`

```
 cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("GETBOOKMARK", "call dialog cancel");
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

public void cancel ()
```

*Cancel the dialog. This is essentially the same as calling dismiss(), but it will also call your DialogInterface.OnCancelListener (if registered).*

```
public void dismiss ()
```

*Dismiss this dialog, removing it from the screen. This method can be invoked safely from any thread. Note that you should not override this method to do cleanup when the dialog is dismissed, instead implement that in onStop().*

Here is code what is used,

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
            dialog.show();
            ImageView gifView1 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.gifImageView);
            Button declineButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.declineButton);
            Button accecptBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.acceptButton);
            Button rateAppBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rateButton);
            declineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            accecptBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
```

Comment: I also try to use dismiss() function, but nothing change. I cannot close the dialog.

Comment: see my edited answer, i used cancel button, it's working. You should have your `cancelButtonSNS` i.e  `LinearLayout cancelButton = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelButtonSNS);` in `popup_login_sns.xml`

Comment: Thank you so much, I can close the dialog. The problem is the context that I use for creating dialog. I make a mistake in get context for the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your method `dialog.cancel();` to `dialog.dismiss();`

```
 dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.CustomDialogTheme);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_login_sns);

        LinearLayout cancelButton = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelButtonSNS);
            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.d("GETBOOKMARK", "call dialog cancel");
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
```